# Prove the principle of Mathematical Induction from the well-ordering principle.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

There are some similar questions, but I am looking for an explanation of a particular prove. It's a proof by contradiction.

---

**The proof:**

Suppose A contains 1, and that A contains $n+1$ if it contains $n$.
If $A$ doesn't contain all natural numbers, then the set $B$ of natural numbers *not* in A is not **$\varnothing$**.

So $B$ has a smallest member $n_0$. Now $n_0\neq1$, since $A$ contains 1, so we can write $n_0=(n_0-1)+1$, where $n_0-1$ is a natural number. Now $n_0-1$ is *not* in $B$, so $n_0-1$ *is* in $A$. By hypothesis, $n_0$ must be in $A$, so $n_0$ is not in $B$, a contradiction.

---

That ends the proof. I do not quite understand how it proves it (I am new to proofs). I am somewhat familiar to the well-ordering principle and the principle of Mathematical induction. I am mostly confused about the second paragraph of the proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The indirect assumption is that $B=A^c$ is not empty; there are natural numbers in $B$. $1$ is not in $B$ because we assumed that $1\in A$.

Because $1$ is not in $B$ the smallest element of $B$ has a predecessor: $n_0-1$ not in $B$ because a natural number smaller than the smallest one in a set is not in that set.

So, $n_0-1$ is not in $B$; it is in $A$. But, by hypothesis if an element is in $A$ then its successor is also in $A$: $n_0-1+1=n_0$. $n_0$ is in $B$ (its smallest element) and it is in $A$. $B$ is the complement of $A$. So $n_0$ is in $A$ and is in its complement at the same time. Contradiction of the best kind.

Comment: Wow!  That was a very lucid and coherent explanation. Thanks